# RxJs: What is the difference between Subjects and Observable-Multicasting

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I've been learning RxJs for a couple of weeks now and I can't seem to understand what exactly is the differences between Subjects and Multicasting an observable.

I found many sources that differentiate observables with subjects, but I couldn't find any source that differentiated Subjects with Multicasting-Observables

As per my understanding...

> **Multicasting**: allow side-effects to be shared among multiple subscribers.
>
> **Subjects**: is an Observable which shares a single execution path among
> observers.

My questions are:

- What is the difference if both do the same thing?
- When should you use a Subject?
- When should you use multicasting?

Answer (score 4):

Basically "multicasting" means sharing one subscription to a source `Observable` among multiple observers. In RxJS this is always done via the `multicast()` operator that internally uses a `Subject` instance.

`Subjects` are objects that work as both `Observable` and observer at the same time. So typically you'll use `Subjects` to emit custom events whenever you want:

```js
const s = new Subject();
s.next();
s.complete();
```

... but you can use it to subscribe to another Observable and then subscribe to this `Subject` multiple times which is the same thing as multicasting does:

```js
const s = new Subject();
const source = ... // Observable
source.subscribe(s);

s.subscribe(...);
s.subscribe(...);
s.subscribe(...);
```

So there's only one subscription to `source` and 3 subscriptions (observers) to `s` thus you're multicasting emissions from `source` into 3 observers.